# awk 2nd calculation in script

Tags: bash, awk

awk may be giving me a headache. I am trying to sum up a certain number of lines of a certain row.

```
cat /home/logger/uplog.txt | awk 'NR==1,NR==7 {print $5}';
```

I know this only gives me the output of field 1 to 7. What I try is

```
awk 'NR==1,NR==7 {print sum += $5}
```

but the result looks nothing I expected. So how do I manage to make that simple calculation, for this is the second awk-command in that script and therefore read a second time. BTW including this question too, how to write to /dev/null after a certain number of lines within the awk-statement, e.g.

```
(R=0,R<=181,R++)
for R in FNR>=181 /dev/null ;
```

any hints, thanks in advance.

Comment: Field separator and read here on stackoverflow.

Comment: `NR==1,NR==7` means that there  are two patterns separated by a comma: one matches when the record number is 1, and the other when it is 7. So the `{ action }` executes for the first line and for the seventh line. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to only print the `sum`, do `{sum += $5}` and then put the print in an `END` block: `END { print sum }`.

Comment: Also, no `cat` needed. `awk` takes input file arguments: `awk 'script' yourfile`.

Comment: @Kaz: You say, `so the { action } executes for the first line and for the seventh line.` Actually, `awk` supports _range_ syntax similar to `sed`'s: `NR==1,NR==7` refers to the _inclusive range_ of records 1 _through_ 7.

Comment: My bad, X, Y is a range: from the record that matches X, until the record that matches Y, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You are VERY confused about awk syntax, terminology, and behavior. You should get and read the book [*Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000707.do) by Arnold Robbins before trying to write an awk script again.

Let's see if this helps with your current issues though:

To print from field 1 to field 7 of each input record is:

```
{
    for (i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        print $i
    }
}
```

To instead print the sum of the values of those fields would be:

```
{
    sum=0
    for (i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        sum += $i
    }
    print sum
}
```

To write records (lines by default) 5 through 10 to /dev/null would be:

```
NR>=5 && NR<=10 { print > "/dev/null" }
```

Does that answer your current questions?

Comment: Instead of the O'Reilly book, can I put in a counter-suggestion: *The AWK Programming Language* by Aho, Kernighan and Weinberger. It's one of the best programming books of any kind that I've ever read. http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/awkbook/index.html

Comment: That book was written almost 30 years ago and so is WAY out of date and missing all of the features of modern awks. I would not get it.

Comment: That book is written by *the creators* of AWK, and it covers (conservatively) 80% of the most useful features of all AWKs. Your answer, but I cannot disagree more strongly over which book is more valuable.

Comment: The other book is written by the creator of GNU awk, which is much more relevant today than the mid-1970s tool commonly referred to today as old, broken awk. Yes, that old book covers 80% of awk functionality but the new book covers almost 100%, including all the modern staples and POSIX functionality. There's really no comparison - getting that old awk book would be like buying a 1980s manual on operating a TV.

Comment: You really are completely missing the point. The [Robbins book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000707.do)--not one 'b', by the way--is fine. It's a perfectly fine, mediocre book. I'm sure it covers lots of the shiny features of GNU awk. The other is a classic that will help you learn more about *programming period*. Your 1980s TV manual is utterly misplaced. The whole point of the Aho, Kernighan and Weinberger book is that it's *not* just a manual.

Comment: Most people do not need to read an awk book to learn programming in general, but instead how to apply programming principles using the awk language. That is where, IMHO, the old book is bound to fail. I have read both books and I can't imagine why you think so highly of the old one but I don't understand why the Twilight books were so well received either so maybe it's me. If it works for you, more power to you.